# Procedures and system calls in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls, procedures, mips32

This program asks the user for an integer then it jumps to `check511` label. There it checks whether the given number is greater or smaller than `511`.

If it's greater than `511` it returns `1` else it returns `0`.

After this it goes back to `Print` label and gives the result. I did this using two registers `$v0` and `$v1`.

I want to know, is there any way that it can be done using only `$v0`?

```
.data 
 prompt: .asciiz "Enter a Integer\n"
 result: .asciiz "The result is "

.text
.globl main
 main:
     # prompt the user for Integer
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0, prompt 
     syscall

     # getting integer from the user
     li $v0, 5
     syscall

     add $a0, $v0, $zero #putting the input in $a

     jal check511 #jump to procedure check511

 Print:
     #print result statement
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0, result
     syscall

     # Print answer
     li   $v0, 1
     addi $a0, $v1, 0
     syscall

     #exit program
     li $v0, 10   
     syscall

 check511:
     bgt  $a0, 511,   Else #branch to else is > 511
     addi $v1, $zero, 0   
     j Print

 Else:
     addi $v1, $zero, 1
     j Print
```

Comment: Sure, save the function return value on the stack temporarily. Whether that's better or not is up to you to decide.

Comment: Check SLTIU then xor result with 1.

Comment: You should be using `jr $ra` instead of `j Print` to return from the function.

Comment: @markgz yes, i thought about that using `$ra` is more efficient it was working good with `j Print` as well so i didn't change it